# Configuration with name "kapt" not found in multi-module project

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am trying to build a multi-module Android project.

I have an implementation class to register a Gradle plugin:

```
import ...

class AndroidHiltConventionPlugin : Plugin<Project> {

    override fun apply(target: Project) {
        with(target) {
            with(pluginManager) {
                apply("dagger.hilt.android.plugin")
                apply("org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt")
            }

            val libs = extensions.getByType<VersionCatalogsExtension>().named("libs")
            dependencies {
                "implementation"(libs.findLibrary("hilt.android").get())
                "kapt"(libs.findLibrary("hilt.compiler").get())
                "kaptAndroidTest"(libs.findLibrary("hilt.compiler").get())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, I am getting the following error when trying to use the plugin:

```
Failed to apply plugin 'todo.android.hilt'.
   > Configuration with name 'kapt' not found.
```

The traceback says the problem is with the line:

```
"kapt"(libs.findLibrary("hilt.compiler").get())
```

What is going wrong here?

Is this something I must add to the project Gradle build file, as I currently do not have `kapt` there?

However, the [Now In Android sample app](https://github.com/android/nowinandroid/blob/main/build.gradle.kts) (which I am following) does not seem to have it there.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I realised `kapt` is included in the Kotlin compiler. I added a plugin which provided the Kotlin compiler before the hilt plugin.

Comment: @woxiangqui, did you solve this? I am also facing similar issue after following nowinandroid. the above description is not clear to me. could you please elaborate more

Comment: @VenkatBallem whenever you add the hilt convention plugin to a Gradle file, before it, add the Android library plugin.